# How to describe, in a schematic, grounding to the base/body of a potentiometer?

Tags: schematics, wiring, potentiometer

I am working on updating a guitar project I did many, many years ago. I mean, I could just do a 'symbolic' drawing of the wiring itself, but since I have more experience now, for my records I'd just like to draw up a formal schematic.

My question relates not so much to the context of my project *per se*, but more so, in general, how does one properly handle on a schematic any wiring or component use which is perhaps 'non-standard'?

e.g. In my case I have the three pins connected to the potentiometer, but also a ground wire going to the body/base of the pot itself. Mind you, not 'unheard of' in guitar work, but also (I think?) rather 'non-standard' on a schematic.

Question pertains to the potentiometer here, but also how to handle any other 'non-standard' wiring case. Don't know 'best practice'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put notes in the schematic as well as pictures of special assembly procedures. You could also draw a special symbol with a forth pin attached to a dashed box around the resistor symbol which is the body of the pot.

In a commercial environment, this is covered in special assembly instructions since schematics are not part of the assembly documentation.